# Replace text and move cursor to end of replacement in insert mode

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement, insert-mode, filetype-tex

How can I perform a search-and-replace and leave the cursor at the end of the replacement? I want to replace $...$ with \(...\) as I type in insert mode.

Notice that I can't use an abbreviation, since $ is replaced with two different strings.

The solution I've cobbled together so far is equivalent to:

```
function Foo()
    let pat = '\$\(.\{-}\)\$'
    if line =~ pat
        execute 's/' . pat . '/\\(\1\\)/'
        call cursor('.', matchend(getline('.'), '\\)'))
    endif
endfunction

inoremap $ $<C-O>:call Foo()<CR>
```

Is there a better way to do this? The only alternative I found is to add the length of '\\)' to the column number from searchpos, and that isn't any nicer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get this effect is to instead adaptively enter either `\(` or `\)` depending on which is needed.  So the first `$` will type `\(` and the second will type `\)`.  To figure out which we need, we use `searchpairpos`, which returns `[0,0]` when outside the `\(..\)` pair.  Besides being cleaner to code, it is also a bit nicer while typing and works over multiple lines.

```
function! IDollar()
  let [l:l,l:c] = searchpairpos('\\(', '', '\\)', 'cbWn')
  return l:l ? '\)' : '\('
endfunction

inoremap <silent><expr> $ IDollar()
```

If you would rather the exact behavior mentioned in your question, here is an improved version of your script.  There are a few differences:

1. use `setline` instead of `s/` because there are fewer side-effects,
2. use `cursor()` since we know the cursor always needs to move forward by 2,
3. use the `<c-r>=` pattern instead of `<c-o>` since `<c-o>` resets the last insert position (useful when `backspace` does not contain `start`).

```
function! Foo()
  let l:pat = '\$\([^\$]\+\)\$'
  let l:line = getline('.')
  if l:line =~ l:pat
    call setline('.', substitute(l:line, l:pat, '\\(\1\\)', ''))
    call cursor(0, col('.')+2)
  endif
  return ''
endfunction
inoremap $ $<c-r>=Foo()<cr>
```

Comment: I can't imagine a better answer than this, but I'll wait for a while before I accept it, just in case.

Comment: Your first solution is perfect, and taught me a lot about the search functions. Your second solution is also very educational.

Comment: upvote for `<c-r>=` alone.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround)

```
let g:surround_{char2nr('R')} = "\\(\r\\)"
imap $ $<esc>cs$R`]a
```

The idea is to create a custom surrounding, "R", which is `\(...\)`. We use this surrounding to replace `$...$`. Use the `']` mark to restart the insert at the end of the changed text.

For more help see:

```
:h surround-customizing
:h surround-mappings
:h ']
:h char2nr(
:h curly-braces-names
```